# スマートポインタを用いた変数の出力方法について

Tags: c++

std::coutを使ってnum1,num2を出力したいです。
以下のコード(1)と(2)があるのですが、この場合のfor文の書き方が分かりません。

```
struct Data {
std::shared_ptr<std::array<SomeData, 30>> ptr1; //(1)
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<SomeData>>> ptr2; //(2)
};

struct SomeData {
int16_t num1;
int32_t num2;
SomeData():
num1(0),
num2(0){}
};
```

式(1)(2)を用いる場合、次の関数でnum1とnum2の値を出力するには、どのような記述が効果的でしょうか。

```
void func(const Data& data_info)
{
    //記述
}
```

Comment: スマートポインタじゃない変数だったらこういう風にforループを書くんだけど、shared_ptr使ってるからできないみたいな例は挙げられますか？

Comment: (1)がスマートポインタでない場合(std::array<SomeData, 30> ptr1;の場合)は関数内にて、
for(const auto& some_data : data_info.ptr1) {
    std::cout << some_data.num1 << std::endl;
 }
の様に記述できると思ったのですがshared_ptrがついた途端分からなくなってしまいました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スマートポインタは基本的な操作を通常のポインタと同じようにできるように定義されているので、次のように書けます。

```
void func(const Data& data_info)
{
  if (data_info.ptr1) { // nullチェック
    for (const auto& some_data : *data_info.ptr1) { // 逆参照
      std::cout << some_data.num1 << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```